# Inject into base class property with Ninject

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, ninject

I have a viewmodel which extends a base class called BaseModel which in turn has a property of type DbContext.

How do I get ninject to inject the DbContext into the base class when calling the drived class?

Answer (score 2):

The most reliable way is to make it a required constructor parameter:

```
public abstract class BaseModel
{
    private DbContext dbContext;

    protected BaseModel(DbContext dbContext) { this.dbContext = dbContext; }

    protected DbContext DbContext { get { return this.dbContext; } }
}
```

Then in your view models, simply pass the DbContext into the base class:

```
public CustomerViewModel : BaseModel
{
    public CustomerViewModel(DbContext dbContext)
        : base(dbContext) { }
}
```

It sounds like you don't quite understand how to use Ninject properly, for the example I have given, all you need to do is register 1 binding

```
kernel.Bind<DbContext>().To<MyDbContext>(); // Or whatever your DbContext is called.
```

Then you can resolve the view model like this:

```
var viewModel = kernel.Resolve<CustomerViewModel>();
```

You would only need to register a binding for `CustomerViewModel` if you needed to resolve that as a dependency for another class.

Comment: This would require me to add a binding for every viewmodel though which is what I am trying to get away from. I was hoping to have a single binding for the base class which would be used each time a derived class is instantiated.

Comment: No, all you need to do is add a binding for `DbContext` - it sounds like you have a miss understanding of how dependency injection works.

Comment: @TrevorPilley this doesn't work in ninject 3.2.0, it complains about it being a circular dependency

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the base class' property is

- public and has a public setter:
- is annotated with the [Ninject.Inject] attribute

For example:

```
abstract class AbstractFoo
{
    [Ninject.Inject]
    public DbContext DbContext { get; set; }
}
```

Also see the [Ninject Wiki on Property Injection](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Injection-Patterns#property-setter-injection)

### Required Binding(s)

(For future readers: This is not really in regard to the original question but needs answering because the poster was unaware of when bindings need to be created.)

Also, you will need a binding per type you want to be injected into some other type (or resolved directly from the kernel).

Given the following:

```
public class DerivedFoo : AbstractFoo
{
}
```

and some class `Service` where it should be injected into:

```
public class Service
{
     public Service(DerivedFoo foo)
     { ... }
}
```

requires a binding like:

```
Bind<DerivedFoo>().ToSelf();
```

Hint: well actually in this exact case the binding is not necessary, since with ninject's default configuration, if the type to resolve - in this case the constructor parameter `DerivedFoo foo` is a class with accessible constructor (`abstract class` => would not be accessible!), then ninject behaves *as if* you would have created the above binding. You can disable this behavior so that ninject *only* resolves types you've actually created a binding for.

### Resolving an Abstract Type

If the service would look slightly different, let's say:

```
public class Service
{
     public Service(AbstractFoo foo)
     { ... }
}
```

you would need a binding like

```
Bind<AbstractFoo>().To<DerivedFoo>();
```

### Resolving an Interface

Also in the following case where an interface is injected instead of a class, you would need a binding:

```
public class Service
{
     public Service(IFoo foo)
     { ... }
}

Bind<IFoo>().To<DerivedFoo>();
```

### Reducing the amount of "Binding Work" you have to do

In some cases it makes sense to use [Ninject.Extensions.Conventions](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions) in order to reduce the amount of `Bind...` code you need to write.
Note however, that conventions *should* be specific and easy to remember, and they should not *overlap* (overlap = multiple conventions apply to the same type).
Also look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075389/how-to-bind-using-ninject-conventions-extension) for some more information regarding convention bindings.

Comment: That will only work if you add the `[Ninject.Inject]` attribute on it - from the link you specified "For a property to be injected it must be annotated with [Inject]"

Comment: it is public and does have a public setter. However I am new to Ninject and  non of my bindings are working. I can get the binding to work if I bind directly to the derived class but not the base class.

Comment: @coolblue2000 you don't need to have a binding for an `abstract` base class. You always need the binding for the concrete (derived) type. Well actually you need the binding for the type you're injection. For example if there's some other class `Bar` which takes `AbstractFoo` as ctor parameter, then you need a binding like `Bind<AbstractFoo>().To<DerviedFoo>();`. The `To` part must never be an `abstract` type.

Comment: So there is no way around having to bind to each view model meaning there could be hundreds of bindings?

Comment: @coolblue2000 exactly. You can use [Ninject.Extensions.Conventions](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions) so you don't have to specifically write a binding for every single type, but the kernel will still need to have a binding for each type which should be resolvable (=> injectable). Small correction, if you're resolving types which can be constructed directly (non abstract class with accessible constructor) technically you don't need a binding because ninject will do the same as if you've done `Bind<Foo>().ToSelf().InTransientScope()`

Comment: @TrevorPilley thanks. I actually wanted to write exactly that but somewhere during the writing process i completely forgot about it (I usually write an answer while waiting for a build to complete.. and so i sometimes pause in between which occasionally leads to me forgetting to include important things...). I've updated the post accordingly.